Where is 512M RAM from?
In Virtual machine, Kali, I assigned the memory 4G, like this;
But there is a problem.
I installed self-build kernel at the guest to hack the memory.
# uname -a
Linux 15ud490-gx76k 6.8.4+ #8 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apt 6 15:49:20 KST 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And I want to see an erea of end of memory, typed like below.

It says a size of memory is 16*0x336000 bytes.
Then I inferenced the memory size with the results (On the host).
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 16*0x07fff0
8388352
>>> 16*0x07fff0/1024/1024
7.999755859375
>>> 16*0x335ff0/1024/1024
51.374755859375
>>> 16*0x336000/1024/1024
51.375
>>> 521000/1024/1024
0.49686431884765625
>>> (1024*1024*4+521000+3288)*1024/1024/1024/1024 # Convert into gigabytes
4.5

I gave the memory 4G to guest but it has 4.5GiB according to the above.
The swap is 1G so it's nonsense.
Where is the source of 0.5G memory?????

Please don't post images of text

Neither is the physical memory space built for your RAM necessarily contiguous, nor is RAM the only thing that gets physical addresses: your computer has memory-mapped buses / devices.
Try cat /proc/iomem to see the mapping of devices to physical memory space. lsmem greatly simplifies what is really the address space mapping!
This is by no means specific to Linux: that's how pretty much all modern computer architectures work.
Now in your specific case, I guess the extra "truly RAM" that you see are actually not that, but trapped addresses used for communication between hypervisor and VM.

The cat /proc/iomem should be run as root, otherwise depending on kernel configuration, modern kernels might display all the address ranges as all-zeroes.

Your output of lsmem shows 4 memory blocks "missing", namely blocks 28-31. Your memory block size is 128M, summing to a total size of 512M. These 4 blocks account for your "extra" memory. lsmem doesn't report these as usable memory, so what are they and where did they come from?
The addresses corresponding to the gap in your memory are IO memory. According to this old but still relevant HOWTO,

When you insert a card that uses iomem, you are in effect also inserting a memory module for main memory. [...]  Shared memory is shared between the device and the CPU (running the device driver) just as IO address space is shared between the device and the CPU. This shared memory serves as a means of data "transfer" between the device and main memory.

Check the output of # cat /proc/iomem, and you will see which devices have their physical memory mapped into the main address space.
